# Symfony forms post

Tags: forms, symfony1

I read about Symfony forms and i have simple question : 
 i Make 2 templates  "test" and test1 . I  want to post forms values of 
test to test1 and after to show them with echo.
In test i put:

```
form action="<?php echo url_for('maraton/test') ?>" method="POST" />
    <table> 
     <tr>
        <?php echo $form?>
     </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
 </form>
```

my action is :

```
public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
     $this->form = new AthletesForm();
  }

  public function executeTest1(sfWebRequest $request)
     {
        $this->form = new AthletesForm();

           if ($request->isMethod('post'))
             {
                $values = $this->form->getValues();
              }
```

Comment: I dont particularly understand your question - have a read of this to get a better understanding of how forms work in symfony -> http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a form you create it using an action :

```
public function executeContact($request)
{
  $this->form = new sfForm();
}
```

Then to display that form you use a template

```
<?php echo $form->renderFormTag('foo/contact') ?> // this route "foo/contact" points to the action that will process the submit
  <table>
    <?php echo $form ?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Then to process the form submit you use either the same action as above or a seperate action :

```
if ($request->isMethod('post')) 
// this if statement would be added if you used the same action to 
// create / process the submit of the form 
{
  $this->form = new sfForm(); // create an empty form object
  $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('contact')); 
  // merges (binds) the post data with the form
  if ($this->form->isValid()) // if the data is valid
  {
    // Handle the form submission
    $contact = $this->form->getValues();
    $name = $contact['name'];

    // Or to get a specific value
    $name = $this->form->getValue('name');

    // Do stuff
    // persist to database / save to file etc
    $this->redirect('foo/bar');
  }
```

Comment: tnx for answer . its very helpful for me . I have another . if i need to make confirm page whit form info ? press submit and data sent to confirm page and then i save form data  ?

Comment: if you take the $this->$form->bind() request - that adds all of the values into the $this->form object - so at that point you could render it using a template and it would contain the values yes - then after another submit save them in a db or file or anything ...